# Django absolute url works but relative url does not for static files

Tags: python, django, web, static

I have searched around and apologize if this is a basic question.  I am trying to get my django app to serve static files.  If the STATIC_URL is set to the absolute path (ie `http://localhost/static`) then the files work however if STATIC_URL is relative like /static/ it doesn't pull in any static files.

I would like it to be able to use /static/ for when I move the application to a production server and have a reverse proxy serving the static files.

Comment: `/static/` is not relative. That's absolute. A directory in your filesystem ... `cd /static/`. Listen to Topro (sorta) for a typical setup to set absolute directories relative to your project root.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say STATIC_URL in this post.  STATIC_ROOT is set properly but the pages will not find the files unless STATIC_URL is a full url with domain name.

Comment: Are the requests going to the correct place? (rendered HTML look good to you?)

Comment: The urls using {{STATIC_URL}} look fine but django will not find them at all unless they have a full domain and path. Anything like just /static/ gives a 404. Basically: 
`STATIC_URL=http://foobar/static` is good
`STATIC_URL=/static/` is a 404
This one variable is the all or nothing for some reason for my app finding static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django requires `STATIC_DIR` to be absolute path.

set a variable like `PROJECT_DIR` to `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`.

then set `STATIC_DIR` to `os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')`